# Xero Oauth 2.0 sdk

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, sdk, xero-api

Could someone from Xero confirm.

What are the paramaters required to make request using sdk in xero accounting? 
Previously in Oauth 1.0 I used parameter such as client id and client secret and I store them in our database. How different it would be if I now need to switch to Oauth 2.0. 
I am using Node js.

Comment: As I understand it, you need to call a browser to have a user log in to Xero. That will return a token which you can then use in your code, and renew as required. There is some c# sample code on the developer forum. It does not appear to be possible to do it entirely unattended as it was using the older method.

Comment: @droopsnoot in Oauth 2.0 should i store the access token and refresh token, client id and client secret in my database in exchange of consumer key and consumer secret in Oauth 1.0 ?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't got it working yet.